# Apache Rewrite. Rewrite to URL if URL contains a string

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to achieve the following setup but I am struggling to write it in the apache syntax required:

If URL contains "smeghead" then redirect to smeghead.php?(full url copied here).

It is for a permissions issue, I want to run the string it passes in to smeghead.php to a permissions function.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may need adjustment depending on how you have things set up, but this is basically the rule you need:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule smeghead smeghead.php?${REQUEST_URI}
```

REQUEST_URI is everything after the domain name, so if you need the domain name included in what's sent to smeghead.php, do something like this:

```
RewriteRule smeghead smeghead.php?http://www.domain.com${REQUEST_URI}
```